# C++ reading command in txt file using Pipe

Tags: c++, pipe

I hope everyone is doing well. I am confused about a question.
the question says -
CREATE_PEER [id]|[name] -> This command used to create and add a new Peer object to your DLT network. The text following the command will be used to initialize the peers name. Notice that each data point is separated by a '|'(pipe) character.
NB. There is a txt file where there is

CREATE_PEER 1|Dallas

I think the program has to read the txt file and create the peer object.
how am i suppose to do it? read text from txt file then seperate by " " and separate the parameter by "|" and run CREATE_PEER function ? or how can i achieve this using pipe?

I tried to do something like this below code which takes user input and uses pipe. It works but I am not sure If that is the correct way to do it and I am sure that my solution does not answer the question above. Can some one please help how can i read the command using a pipe ?

```
void CREATE_USER(){
Peer *tempPeer = new Peer();
int fd[2];
//fd[0] - read
//fd[1] - write
if(pipe(fd) ==-1){
    cout << "Error in opening pipe";
    return;
}
int id = fork();
if (id==-1){
    cout << "Error in fork";
    return;
}
if(id == 0){
    close(fd[0]);
    int x;
    cout << "Input Peer Id: ";
    cin >> x;
    //::scanf("%d", &x);
    write(fd[1], &x, sizeof(int));
    close(fd[1]);
}else{
    close(fd[1]);
    int y;
    read(fd[0], &y, sizeof(int));
    close(fd[0]);
    cout << "got the value %d\n";
    //cout<< y;
    tempPeer->setId(&y);
}


//reading and writing
int cd[2];
if(pipe(cd) ==-1){
    cout << "Error in opening pipe";
    return;
}
int id2 = fork();
if (id2==-1){
    cout << "Error in fork";
    return;
}
if(id2 == 0){
    close(cd[0]);
    string z;
    cout << "Input Peer name: ";
    //::scanf("%d", &z);
    cin >> z;
    write(cd[1], &z, sizeof(string));
    close(cd[1]);
}else{
    close(cd[1]);
    string k;
    read(cd[0], &k, sizeof(string));
    close(cd[0]);
    cout << "got the value %d\n";
    //cout<< y;
    tempPeer->setPeerName(&k);
}


cout << *tempPeer->getId();
cout << *tempPeer->getName();
```

Comment: Looks like you have questions about the assignment.  Assignment issues and questions are the realm of your instructor.  We can only guess about the requirements since we don't know who your instructor is nor do we have a method to contact your instructor.

Comment: Its just i wanted to know how can i write a pipe where will satisfy this - CREATE_PEER 1|Dallas command